# Network Often Misclassifies One Class

Tags: python, machine-learning, resnet

We've built a ResNet model and it is often misclassifying a few classes way more than any others.  How should we take advantage of this knowledge to boost our accuracy?

We have a dataset containing 100,000 samples, consisting of 100 categories, where each category contains 1,000 pictures.

Our network is fairly simple; taken from PyTorch ResNet-18. Not modified any further.

EDIT: Code is literally the same as ResNet-18 tutorials.  Data are images and their names, say

**IN:** [128x128 pixels]

**OUT:** House

I'm looking for broad tips on how to deal with this type of situation. Not necessarily debugging tips.

:: Y axis denotes accuracy.

[image]

Comment: Sharing your code and a sample of the data would be helpful in giving you more pointers.